# Create array list with mixed types in Java

Tags: java, calculator

Well, it looks like it is not possible. But how can i evaluate a postfix expression without having an operator in the stack of numbers?

Ok: I'll try again.

I want to build a basic calculator. The user will write input numbers. I want to add these into a stack (list), and when the user hits/writes execute the program should evaluate it in postfix manner.

Comment: You need to provide way more information for this question to be answerable in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base class of ExpressionToken and have NumberToken and OperatorToken extend it. Parameterize the ArrayList as a list of ExpressionTokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an `ArrayList` of `Object`s and then put any type you wish inside:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Now you can add anything. When you extract you will get an `Object` back, so make sure to test for the actual type:

```
if(list.get(i) instanceof Number) {
   //
} else if(list.get(i) instanceof Operator) {
   //
}
```

this is assuming you have classes `Number` and `Operator` defined in your program to represent a number and operator respectively.

Comment: Creating a list of `Object`s and adding casting makes the code harder to follow, more error prone and is generally bad practice.